# How to stop Safari from unzipping files after download

Tags: macos, safari

Safari unzips .zip and .gz files after downloading. How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In the menu bar, go Safari -> Preferences. In the "General" tab, uncheck "Open 'safe' files after downloading". This will stop Safari from automatically unzipping the files.

[image: Safari Settings, General tab]

Comment: don't know since when it is the case, but for me and a fresh mojave installation the checkbox did not appear. i **first** had to **activate developer options** under **Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar**. Afterwards more options appeared on the general tab.

Comment: This is a workaround with side effect: all opening of files after download becomes disabled. A full solution without side effects given by @redochka: hold `⌥ alt` when clicking to download. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115634/330523

Answer (score 27):

Just hold the <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> button while clicking on the download links.

<sup>Tested on OS X Mavericks, Big Sur, Monterey. Still works in October 2022.</sup>

Comment: Still works fine in Yosemite, and is a useful "I only want to do this occasionally" option.

Comment: Still works on Big Sur (Intel)

Comment: Still works on Monterey 12.6 (ARM) as well in October 2022

Comment: Still works on Ventura 13.1 in Mach 2023

Answer (score 2):

In Preferences, at the bottom of the General tab, uncheck the "Open "safe" files after downloading" check box.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20051221220935102) if you want to keep the "Safe Downloads" behavior but tweak it a little.

Comment: Please provide a full answer, do not just link out. This goes against Stackexchange policies.