# Safari - How to retain downloaded zip files?

Tags: safari, archive-utility

I know I can get (Desktop) Safari to stop [unarchiving downloads](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/961/how-to-stop-safari-from-unzipping-files-after-download). I don't mind the files being unarchived. I just don't want the zip archives deleted. Is there a way to do this? (10.8.x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari doesn't handle the unzipping itself, it simply opens the zip with the default program, which is the OS X **Archive Utility**, unless you've changed it.

By default, Archive Utility shouldn't delete zip files, but it's possible the preferences got changed. To stop the archives from being deleted, open Archive Utility, located in `/System/Library/CoreServices/`, then open its preferences.

[image: archive utility preferences]

Change the **After expanding:** setting to *leave archive alone*.

[image]

Comment: Follow-up question.. If I were to change Archive Utility, how would I do so. I don't see options in System Prefs, Safari or Finder..

Comment: What do you mean by change Archive Utility? If you're talking about using a different program for zip files, then it's just like setting the default for any other file type. Get Info (⌘I) in Finder on a zip file, and change the *Open With* setting to a different app ([The Unarchiver](http://unarchiver.c3.cx) is good), then click the *Change All* button.

Comment: of course, a d'oh moment.